# Blurred image is downloaded with prefix of the folder name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the Cloud Function API for making inappropriate images blurred and save on firebase. Everything is good, but the file is downloaded with prefix of the folder name. For example, the image name on firebase is 'unBsdUHUb0aBxegJMaVr6LKXSLL2', but its name gets 'profile_images_unBsdUHUb0aBxegJMaVr6LKXSLL2' when it's downloaded.

```
// Import the Firebase SDK for Google Cloud Functions.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const vision = new Vision();
const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;

const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');

// Checks if uploaded images are flagged as Adult or Violence and if so blurs them.
exports.blurOffensiveImages = functions.runWith({memory: '2GB'}).storage.object().onFinalize(
  async (object) => {
    const image = {
      source: {imageUri: `gs://${object.bucket}/${object.name}`},
    };

    // Check the image content using the Cloud Vision API.
    const batchAnnotateImagesResponse = await vision.safeSearchDetection(image);
    const safeSearchResult = batchAnnotateImagesResponse[0].safeSearchAnnotation;
    const Likelihood = Vision.types.Likelihood;
    if (Likelihood[safeSearchResult.adult] >= Likelihood.LIKELY ||
        Likelihood[safeSearchResult.violence] >= Likelihood.LIKELY || 
        Likelihood[safeSearchResult.spoof] >= Likelihood.LIKELY) {
      console.log('The image', object.name, 'has been detected as inappropriate.');
      return blurImage(object.name);
    }
    console.log('The image', object.name, 'has been detected as OK.');
    return null;
  });

// Blurs the given image located in the given bucket using ImageMagick.
async function blurImage(filePath) {
  const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
  const messageId = filePath.split(path.sep)[1];
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

  // Download file from bucket.
  await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempLocalFile});
  await bucket.file(filePath).delete();
  console.log('Image has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
  // Blur the image using ImageMagick.
  await spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-channel', 'RGBA', '-blur', '0x24', tempLocalFile]);
  console.log('Image has been blurred');
  // Uploading the Blurred image back into the bucket.
  await bucket.upload(tempLocalFile, {destination: filePath});
  console.log('Blurred image has been uploaded to', filePath);
  // Deleting the local file to free up disk space.
  fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
  console.log('Deleted local file.');
  // Indicate that the message has been moderated.
  await admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc(messageId).update({moderated: true});
  console.log('Marked the image as moderated in the database.');
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here? What do you expect this code to do instead of what you're saying it does now?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Mr Stevenson.
The image gets saved with prefix and our app can not find the image and display a blank page. So I hope it would be downloaded by its origin name.

Comment: @DougStevenson
Would you help me with this problem? Thank you.